# How generator becomes under excited/ over excited?

Tags: power, power-engineering

I keep reading in power system notes that a generator when under excited/ over excited either absorb/ release reactive power. Question is, what determines these under excitation and over excitation? Rotating rotor produces EMF on stator coils which is injected to grid. I sometimes see that in under excited condition E(terminal voltage) < V(Back EMF) and vis-versa in over excited condition.

What makes E(terminal voltage) constant irrespective of rotor excitation? Should there be some influence of rotor excitation on E?

What happens in case of a Diesel Genset, since there is no concept of constant terminal voltage E?

How to make a Diesel Genset produce active/reactive power, since I don't see the over excitation/ under excitation logic valid here since it is the only power source?

Also, Let us consider that the Diesel Genset is driving a single induction motor. What makes sure that the genset can produce required reactive power?

Comment: There are a lot of different types of generators. Some use speed regulation only, but most use some form of voltage regulation. So they keep the voltage amplitude constant, or, perhaps, reduce voltage slightly when the generator slows down (unable to maintain rated speed). So the genset regulates voltage. The load decides on current and power factor.

Comment: The DC excitation of the rotor of a sychronous machine corresponds with the difference between mechanical and electrical phase. That reflects into the phase shift between voltage and current as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Question is, what determines these under excitation and over excitation?

The amount that the field coils are excited compared to how much they would be excited for a power factor of unity.

> What makes E(terminal voltage) constant irrespective of rotor excitation?

For an introductory class in electric machines, the terminal voltage is presumed to be supplied by the grid.  What makes it constant regardless of rotor excitation is the prof who wrote the book!

> Should there be some influence of rotor excitation on E?

Yes, but that gets into how the grid responds to changes in the output of the generator.  That gets into a whole bunch of really complicated stuff*, which is why you can still get a PhD in electric power generation.

> What happens in case of a Diesel Genset, since there is no concept of constant terminal voltage E?

Well, there is, sort of.  A genset that's driving a synchronous generator** regulates the field coils so that the generator produces the correct voltage.  A direct side effect of this is that the generator will be over- or under-excited as much as it needs to be to match the power factor of the load while delivering the correct voltage.

* Made more complicated by wind and solar energy, and more complicated yet by the rules the utilities have to follow.

** In other words, not just driving a permanent magnet generator that drives an inverter.

Answer (score 0):

> what determines these under excitation and over excitation?

Increasing field current increases the “voltage behind reactance” of the synchronous machine.  Active (P) and reactive (Q) power are fairly [decoupled](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-flow_study#Other_power-flow_methods) such that voltage magnitude determines reactive flow while angular differences determine active flow.

So, higher field current increases air-gap voltage (voltage behind reactance) of the machine relative to terminal voltage.  This would push reactive var out of the machine (or reduce the incoming vars).

Decreasing the field has the opposite effect - we do this intentionally at night when the grid voltage tends to run high.  Units doing this are in what we call condensing mode.

To push active power out you increase mechanical input to increase the angle of the machine relative to the system.

> What makes E(terminal voltage) constant irrespective of rotor excitation?

It isn’t, but in strong grid it can approximate infinite bus.

> What happens in case of a Diesel Genset, since there is no concept of constant terminal voltage E?

Same exact mechanisms.  The voltage regulator maintains terminal voltage per desired operating mode.